# how can I determine if my project is using automatic reference counting

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have been experiencing a problem where an object that I am using in a cocos2D box2D project is overwritten with garbage. After a good bit of debugging, I found that if the following line was changed from:

```
player = [[[Player alloc] initWithWorld:world atLocation:ccp(playerPositionX, playerPositionY)] autorelease];
```

to

```
player = [[Player alloc] initWithWorld:world atLocation:ccp(playerPositionX, playerPositionY)];
```

then the problem goes away. This is very confusing because this code and the underlying class definition is more or less a copy of code from the SpaceViking project described in the Learning Cocos2D book.

It occurred to me that perhaps the problem is that when I created the new project, I may have left the choice for Automatic Reference Counting selected, whereas I may not have done that for the SpaceViking project. I am currently using xcode 4.6 and can't figure out how to determine if ARC is being used in this project. I went to the build settings and searched for automatic reference counting, but could not find it.

How can I determine if my project is using automatic reference counting?

Comment: You can't be using ARC if you are able compile a call to `autorelease`.  Note that you can turn ARC off/on for individual files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
/* ARC is used */
#endif
```

Comment: Ok, I put a CCLOG statement within your suggested #if #endif block and nothing was printed. So I assume that I am not using ARC. That is unfortunate, because that means I still have a problem that I cannot figure out.

Comment: @JeffB6688 Tried compiling using the `-fobjc-arc` flag? That should enable automatic ref counting.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think I will hold off on this. I need to find the root of the problem because I am finding that every time I create a box2D body/fixture, I am having the same memory management problem. Each created box2d body/fixture creates a Box2DSprite object that is alloc'd and autoreleased. Then my update method is attempting to update the position of this box2d sprite, but the Box2DSprite has garbage in it. But as I said, this is the same code used in the SpaceViking project. Very frustrating.

Comment: @JeffB6688 It is, indeed. Try to remove the calls to `release` and `autorelease` one by one, then see when it won't crash. You then have a starting point :)

Comment: @H2CO3 OK, I found the problem. I forgot to add the created Box2DSprite object as a child to the CCSpriteBatchNode. So I guess that means that nothing had ownership of the object, so they were autoreleased.

Comment: @JeffB6688 Exactly, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
[player release];
```

It should give you "ARC Restrictions" Errors

Comment: OK, thanks. I tried this also and I am not getting any error. So I assume that I am not using ARC. That is unfortunate, because that means I still have a problem that I cannot figure out.

Comment: This is not how one **should** check for using ARC.

Comment: Nice way to check :)  **How to check if Heaven actually exist? -Jump from Eiffel Tower and check.**

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Nailed it down :D

Answer (score 1):

You can already tell you're building without ARC: were it enabled, your call to `autorelease` would result in a compiler error. This suggests that your actual problem has nothing to do with ARC, of course -- removing the `autorelease` call may be preventing an object from getting over-released, but it's also quite possibly causing a leak.

Besides that, though: in addition to the other methods that have been suggested so far, you can also find the place in Xcode where one normally controls ARC at the project- or target-wide level. Select your project in the navigator, and in the Build Settings tab, look for "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" under "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 - Language" (or use the search box at the top to look for "Automatic Reference Counting" or "ARC". If you're using a project somebody else originally set up, you may also wish to check for whether the `-fobjc-arc` or `-fno-objc-arc` flags are set at a per-file level. That's under Build Phases -> Compile Sources when your project and target are selected in Xcode.